# PHP & Magento If statement based on page url

Tags: php, magento

I want to create the following conditional statement based on the cms page url to show a different background image for my magento store. Syntax seems good, but it doesn't show up.

```
<?php
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'):
       $Page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle(); 
endif;   

if($Page == 'about-us'):
       //echo $this->getChildHtml('bg_aboutus');
      echo '<div class="bg"><img src="' . $this->getSkinUrl("images/about_us.jpg") . '" alt="office interiors" ></div>';
endif;                        
?>
```

Comment: What *does* show up? What are the values? What does `$Page` contain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use this to add condition in your page

```
 <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'about-us') != false ) :

 echo '<div class="bg"><img src="' . $this->getSkinUrl("images/about_us.jpg") . '" alt="office interiors" ></div>';
endif; 

 endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks liyakat! That works... How do i know modify to show a diferent background for say contacts or services cms page..

Comment: just change in if condition about-us to contacts or services with your page url will please accept my answer, so some one can use it in future reference

Answer (score 2):

Here are the ways you can router or method action information anywhere in Magento :

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); // return controller name

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName(); // return action name

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); // return routes name

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName(); // return module name


to get module, controller, action name
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```